# Can I initialize bootstrap carousel in a function? or it should be done only in ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
  $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: false
    });
```

I want to initialize this in a function but it is not working.

Is there any way to do this?

FYI I tried placing it in the `document.ready` function.

Comment: thanks for the edit @JoseM :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember you have to load the `jquery.js` (library) file

and then load the bootstrap jquery file and then you custom js file.

Then call the carousel function like this

`$('.carousel').carousel() // here carousel is the class of a div`

add additional options like this

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    })
});
```

If you are including this script within the html page, take care to see that you are including this function calling near the end of the html page.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize function in anywhere in function. But when you call same function again then it will be re-initialize. So keep it mind the re-initialization functionality.